# Blender physics animation into powerpoint

Tags: animation, physics

I'm trying to export an animation that I made using physics in Blender into a PowerPoint slide (import 3D). I was able to export simple animation by putting armature in the object and exporting it as gltf file and import in PowerPoint as a 3D image. but any idea how can I export an animation by physics in a Blender into PowerPoint?

Answer (score 0):

If it's rigid body animations, you can bake it into keyframes on the objects:

1. select the objects
2. operator search (<kbd>F3</kbd>) > Bake Animation
3. Bake

If it's physics simulations that deform or generate new mesh, you will need to export as alembic but I don't know if Powerpoint supports it.

If it's other things like smoke, I don't think you can.

Comment: Thanks for the response. it is a rigid body animation. I baked the animation and exported it as gltf but it doesn't show the animation in the PowerPoint. did you try yourself that and you see the animation in the PowerPoint? if so, maybe I'm exporting it in a wrong way.

Comment: No, I don't have powerpoint. To be honest I don't expect a slideshow software to have a great support for 3D files anyway. Why not render an animation into a lightweight video file instead?